# Does Apache Drill Support Excel Files (.xls)

Tags: apache-drill

I am trying to query for excel files (.xls) through dfs storage plugin:-

```
select * from dfs.`E:/Demos/Sample.xls`;
```

But It throwing some error:--

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 17: Table 'dfs.E:/Demos/Sample.xls' not found SQL Query null

**Same Problem with Ms Access file.
 if i query through some Microsoft Access(.accdb)files, It throwing error.**

> My Question is :- Whether Apache Drill Supports Excel and Ms Access Files or not.???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a storage plugin for Apache Drill available that supports querying Excel files: https://github.com/bizreach/drill-excel-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Also there is an open PR for Excel plugin in Apache Drill (https://github.com/apache/drill/pull/1749), so most likely it will be available in Drill 1.17.

Answer (score 1):

Drill doesn't currently support querying MS Excel or Access files directly.

Someone asked a similar question on Drill's mailing list and Andries gave him the following answer:

> You can use the Drill ODBC driver, and then query Drill using MS Query
>   or the same way you would query another DB engine through an ODBC DSN.

Comment: :- Would you please share the mailing list link of question which Andries gave answer.??

Comment: sure. [Here it is](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/drill-user/201602.mbox/%3C2347CAE6-9C46-460D-9FE8-F4FF9BA1566A@maprtech.com%3E)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now integrated into Drill.

Comment: Thanks for the info. recently i also came to know that.